# Changing css elements with php by loading php in css file

Tags: php, html, css

I have a page which I can only edit the CSS, so I know I can load a php file via the @import. I wanted to know if its possible to depending on the content of the HTML, the PHP file that is loaded by the css to echo some CSS depending on its content, like this:

```
HTML Element: td , content="PG-13"
PHP: if (td content = "PG-13")
       echo "Oh look its it's suited for children that are older than 13 years old";
```

That above is a code I thought about to simplify my question. If its possible to do this please let me know. Remember that I can only edit the CSS of the original HTML page.

Comment: "PHP file that is loaded by the css" wut?

Comment: If you cannot modify html than it's better if you don't do anything

Comment: [This](http://css-tricks.com/sass-vs-less/) is what you need.

Comment: Nope. You're out of luck if you cannot access the HTML/PHP for this site.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot write PHP code in a .css file.

Comment: I also thought that, but I saw a guy who did it, it echoed the css code via import of a php file